# Google Tags not fired and what should do?

Tags: tags

I just imported a container to Google Tag manager and it goes wrong, [[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg9GL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAMtK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vicrl.png)

Could you please tell me how to fix this? Thanks so much!

I want to make this tag work. Please let me know how, thanks!